# Create subgroups based on dateTime

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

So I have a list of objects within a list, over 600~ of them.

I have a single object example here:

```
{'Description': '', 'Encrypted': False, 'OwnerId': '', 'Progress': '100%', 'SnapshotId': '', 'StartTime': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 16, 22, 47, 50, 383000, tzinfo=tzlocal()) }
```

The problem is that I have a list/array of these and I want to group them all into subgroups such that each object is grouped into a group with others that are timestamped with the "StartTime" datetime that are within 5 minutes of each other. I've been working on this for over a week and I have no idea how to do this grouping. After I group them, I need to apply some rules to each group to ensure they have the correct tags and information.

Just for reference, these are snapshot objects created by amazon aws boto3 describe_snapshots method. You can read about them here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_snapshots

Comment: If you wish to truncate times to the nearest 5 minutes or the like and if you are willing to pip install a small module you might use https://pypi.org/project/time-int/ . [disclaimer, its my own module, and also truncating times into such groups are not necessarily the same thing you described]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas` for this to group the dataframe with `pd.Grouper(key='StartTime', freq='5min')`:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from dateutil.tz import tzlocal

data = [{'Description': '', 'Encrypted': False, 'OwnerId': '', 'Progress': '100%', 'SnapshotId': '', 'StartTime': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 16, 22, 47, 50, 383000, tzinfo=tzlocal()) },{'Description': '', 'Encrypted': False, 'OwnerId': '', 'Progress': '100%', 'SnapshotId': '', 'StartTime': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 16, 22, 48, 50, 383000, tzinfo=tzlocal()) },{'Description': '', 'Encrypted': False, 'OwnerId': '', 'Progress': '100%', 'SnapshotId': '', 'StartTime': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 16, 22, 58, 50, 383000, tzinfo=tzlocal()) },{'Description': '', 'Encrypted': False, 'OwnerId': '', 'Progress': '100%', 'SnapshotId': '', 'StartTime': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 16, 22, 59, 50, 383000, tzinfo=tzlocal()) }]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_grouped = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='StartTime', freq='5min'))
```

Or you could create an extra row in the original dataframe with the number of the group. Eg:

```
def bin_number(table):
    table['bin'] = list(df_grouped.groups.keys()).index(table.name)
    return table

df_grouped = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='StartTime', freq='5min'), as_index=False)
df_grouped = df_grouped.apply(bin_number).reset_index()
```

Output:

|  | index | Description | Encrypted | OwnerId | Progress | SnapshotId | StartTime | bin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |  | False |  | 100% |  | 2021-07-16 22:47:50.383000+02:00 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |  | False |  | 100% |  | 2021-07-16 22:48:50.383000+02:00 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 |  | False |  | 100% |  | 2021-07-16 22:58:50.383000+02:00 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |  | False |  | 100% |  | 2021-07-16 22:59:50.383000+02:00 | 2 |

Comment: In the output you shared, what is that returning? Is it an array of arrays such that each sub-array is the groups?

Comment: This is a [pandas dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). You can export it as a dictionary with `df_grouped.to_dict(orient='records')`, or as many other data formats (see documentation). I would, however, advise to use `pandas` also for further data processing. It's python's main data manipulation module.